# How to manage out of the box monitoring using Kubernetes online endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am learning about Kubernetes online endpoints and my objective is to monitor my resources which are deployed using Kubernetes endpoints. Is there any provision to get out-of-the-box monitoring to Kubernetes online endpoints to check the performance. I am new to this domain. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general monitoring is available and supportive in AKS, but the out of the box implementation was not supportive unfortunately. Check the below documentation and screenshot to refer supportive formats of monitoring in AKS

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-endpoints

Comment: thanks for the response. I guess the way I am trying to approach is wrong.